# removing top value of stack<string> and poping the rest

Tags: c#, winforms, stack

I have a stack in which certain array of strings is pushed.when I want to pop the stack I need to remove the topmost element(the last element that was in) and pop the rest....

```
if (simpleStack.Count > 0)
{
    simpleStack.Peek().Remove(0);
    string open = simpleStack.Pop();

    PopulateListView(open);
    complicatedStack.Push(open);
}
```

I'm trying to peek the element and remove but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: If the stack contains strings, why do you do `ToString()` on a string?

Comment: Peek not remove element from the stack. You could just Pop one element to nowhere.

Comment: Why not just pop the first one and ignore it?

Comment: when i pop one element ...and pop the rest the 2nd element goes missing:/

Comment: You need to look at what the `simpleStack` contains before and after popping the first element. Debug your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is - pop the first item. That will remove it from the stack.

Then you can pop the remaining items.

```
if (simpleStack.Count > 0)
{
    simpleStack.Pop(); // remove top item, discarding it
    string open = simpleStack.Pop(); // Fails if stack has only 1 element

    PopulateListView(open);
    complicatedStack.Push(open);
}
```

Comment: yes it fails when one element is in stack and says stack empty

Comment: im actually implementing it behind the back button in fileExplorer....now when do what u says ..it skips two steps ....

Comment: @engineer41 - `Pop` will only remove one element. Note that you are popping _twice_, saving the _second_ value in `open` - when you `Pop` it _removes_ from the stack - did you expect it to remain there?

Comment: this code is removing 0 and 2 element ...i expect it to only remove one item and show the rest

Comment: can u tell me any way to pop if there is only one element in stack.....its driving me mad..i need to pop the stack if it had one element ...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (simpleStack.Count > 0)
{
    simpleStack.Pop(); // remove top item, discarding it
    string open = simpleStack.Peek(); //removing one element from array and peeking the rest...

    PopulateListView(open);
    complicatedStack.Push(open);
}
```